# Json Convert to Std Object and Access Different data types of a Std Object (i.e Array or Attribute)?

Tags: php, json, amazon-sns

I have a type of a json string converted to std object. returned by the AWS SNS, Some are converted to a Array and some are converted to a Std Object Attribute. I am trying to decode the Attribute "[bouncedRecipients]" from these and its sometimes is a array sometimes its an std object attribute.

unable to go anywhere with it since i tried is below code which only works only if its a JSON object attribute but dont work as array.

```
$mail=json_decode($data->bounce->bouncedRecipients);
```

Here is the a samples of the types of the data returned. Other variabtion type [bouncedRecipients] becomes a std object attribute.

[2016-09-10 04:15:10] SNS Mail

```
stdClass Object
(
    [notificationType] => Bounce
    [bounce] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bounceType] => Permanent
            [bounceSubType] => Suppressed
            [bouncedRecipients] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [emailAddress] => exmaple@gmail.com
                            [action] => failed
                            [status] => 5.1.1
                            [diagnosticCode] => Amazon SES has suppressed sending to this address because it has a recent history of bouncing as an invalid address. For more information about how to remove an address from the suppression list, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/remove-from-suppressionlist.html 
                        )

                )

            [timestamp] => 2016-09-09T22:45:24.978Z
            [feedbackId] => 01000157112sasasec-76df-11e6-9e95-5db9bsasas-000000
            [reportingMTA] => dns; amazonses.com
        )

    [mail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2016-09-09T22:45:05.000Z
            [source] => info@example.com
            [sourceArn] => arn:aws:ses:ssss.com
            [sendingAccountId] => 973549asasas9
            [messageId] => 0100015711207assaasa-4c54-afb2-34f9868a4e1c-000000
            [destination] => Array
                (
                    [0] => example@gmail.com
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already decoded the JSON data, you should be fine just doing something like this:

```
foreach ($data->bounce->bouncedRecipients as $bouncedRecipient) {
    // $bouncedRecipient is an object so use it as such, ie.
    echo $bouncedRecipient->emailAddress;
}
```

If you need to check the type you can also do something like:

```
if (is_object($data->bounce->bouncedRecipients)) {
    $data->bounce->bouncedRecipients = [$data->bounce->bouncedRecipients];
} elseif (!is_array($data->bounce->bouncedRecipients)) {
    die("What is this data you have given me?");
}
```

And then proceed with the previous foreach or similar loop.

Comment: I updated my answer a little bit to address the possibility that it could be an array or an object. 

Let me know if that makes sense.